# Detect when a specific process creates a window (on Windows)

Tags: windows

I have an application which I automate and run in invisible mode. However I want to detect if that application creates and shows any windows so I can interact (or just hide) them.
I'm looking for a way to get notified by the OS that a window was created by the shell.
(I'm using C#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by creating a system wide Windows hook.
Call SetWindowsHookEx with WH_SHELL as the hook id.

In the ShellProc callback function the nCode parameter will have the HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED value whenever a window is created. 
Then I can use GetWindowThreadProcessId to check if the window handle provided in the wParam belongs to the process I am interested in.
This must however be implemented in a native dll since .NET assemblies can only implement system wide hooks for WH_MOUSE_LL and WH_KEYBOARD_LL.